# How to configure Log4cplus Syslog Appender

Tags: syslog, appender, log4cplus

I want to configure Log4cplus Syslog appender to log messages only under certain conditions, by configuring the Log4cplus config file.

The conditions I want to configure are the followings:

1) use sync/Async sending of log messages to Syslog

2) log only messages that contain a certain string/text (for example to log only messages containing the text: "Fail to connect").

```
log4cplus.appender.syslog=log4cplus::SysLogAppende
log4cplus.appender.syslog.ident=syslog
log4cplus.appender.syslog.layout=log4cplus::PatternLayout log4cplus.appender.syslog.layout.ConversionPattern=[%T] %-5p %b %x - %m%n
log4cplus.appender.syslog.host=localhost
log4cplus.appender.syslog.udp=true
log4cplus.appender.syslog.port=514
log4cplus.appender.syslog.facility=user
```

**Is there a way to configure these parameters?**

Answer (score 2):

```
log4cplus.appender.syslog=log4cplus::SysLogAppende
```

You are missing `r`.

```
log4cplus.appender.syslog.layout=log4cplus::PatternLayout log4cplus.appender.syslog.layout.ConversionPattern=[%T] %-5p %b %x - %m%n
```

This should be two lines, not one.

```
log4cplus.appender.syslog.host=localhost
log4cplus.appender.syslog.udp=true
log4cplus.appender.syslog.port=514
```

You do not need to use UDP to log into local syslog on *NIX OS. If you do still want to log into remote syslog using UDP, do not forget to configure the target `syslogd` or similar software to actually accept logging messages from UDP. The default is usually to have remote syslog disabled.